# Can't start zookeeper server

Tags: apache-kafka, port, apache-zookeeper

i tried to start zookeeper with:

```
/opt/Kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  
/opt/Kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties
```

but I got

> ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use

I restarted the computer and I got the same problem
I tried **netstat -nlp|grep 2181** the result:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

**kill -9 2181** --> bash: kill: (2181) - No such process

```
./zookeeper-server-stop.sh  # no result so it works but 
./zookeeper-server-start.sh /opt/Kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/config/zookeeper.properties # the same exception
```

what can I do?

Note: when starting kafka server there is no exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> kill -9 2181 --> bash: kill: (2181) - No such process

You're trying to kill a port number, **not a process ID**.

> Address already in use

Okay, so you clearly already have something on that port.

Options:

1. Edit the `zookeeper.properties` to bind to a different port. Also edit kafka properties to use the new Zookeeper connection.
2. You already have a running Zookeeper, which would explain why Kafka would work when starting.

---

P.S. I would recommend using a later version of Kafka anyway. Lots of good upgrades.